# Creating drill down report in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, drilldown

I am new to JasperReports Server and created some reports. Can anybody explain how to create drill down reports and deploy the same to JasperReports Server?

Comment: You can read [this article](http://www.jaspersoft.com/blog-entry/jasperreport-server-repository-advantage)

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your response. I followed the steps and created a report and its working fine.I want to create a dashboard with two reports. when i click on slice in a pie chart the detail report should be updated accordingly. Could you please tell me how to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: I know this is late. But I had a similar requirement and found the following links useful. This worked for me. http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/hyperlink/index.html http://nukalamadhu.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/jasper-reports-drill-down-facility-inside-a-web-application/